# How to dissect this sentence on its conjunction?

Tags: relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses

Here is a definition of a term, but I'm confused about the usage of the conjunction.

> "The term Emotional or Behavioral Disorder means a disability
>   characterized by behavioral or emotional responses in school so
>   different from appropriate age, cultural, or ethnic norms **that** they
>   adversely affect educational performance."

Why there is no "that is" before "so different"? What does "that" refer to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjective phrases which have following modifiers or complements are placed *after* the noun they modify. In this case, the preposition phrase headed by *from* is the complement of the adjective *different*:

> different *from* appropriate age, cultural, or ethnic norms

Consequently the entire adjective phrase is placed after the noun it modifies, *responses* (so is the locative preposition phrase *in school*).

Some linguists say that such *postposed* ("set after") adjective phrases are actually "reduced" relative clauses—reduced, that is, by omitting the relative pronoun and the form of *BE* at the beginnning. This omitting is called "whiz deletion*, where "whiz" represents *wh-* + *is*.

The *that* you ask about introduces another complementary constituent; in this case the complement of ***so*** different .... In conjunction with *so* the *that* clause tells you how different the responses are: they are ***so*** different **that** they affect educational performance.

This *so ADJ... that CLAUSE* construction is a standard construction:

> That book is **so** sad **that** I cried at the end.
>   She is **so** beautiful **that** men stop and stare when she walks by.

Comment: I think you'll find that "so" only 'licenses' the complement (_that_) clause. The clause is an indirect complement in the structure of the AdjP "different from appropriate age, cultural, or ethnic norms".

Comment: @PaulM W e l l . . . pinning down what licenses what is wonky. It's *so* that evokes the *that* clause; but the *so .. that* complex is dependent on *different*; and *so that* without the *different* means something, well, different: *different* is an integral part of the construction.

Comment: He was hungry enough to eat a horse. He was hungry enough that he could eat a horse.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing. There's no doubt that "so" licenses the that clause because if we drop "so" the AdjP becomes ungrammatical: *"a disability characterized by behavioral or emotional responses in school different from appropriate age, cultural, or ethnic norms that they adversely affect educational performance." But because "so" is modifying the adjective "different", it must belong in the AdjP. I put it badly, but what I really meant was that although the _that_ clause is licensed by "so", it is a dependent in the AdjP headed by "different".

Comment: @PaulM Yah. I've been going back and re-reading McCawley for a sense of how comparative phrases in general are articulated; he doesn't deal with *so ... that* specifically but I think his treatment of *as ... as* and *-er ... than* seems to at first blush extendable to *so ... that* and even *too ... to V*--albeit with a lot of mutatis mutandis. Of relevance to the immediate question is the alternate surface realizations of *er ... than* as *Xer* or *more x*; it's easy enough to imagine a language in which *so* is morphologically incorporated in its head.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers. I really appreciate that! I wanna ask, are there any practical grammar books I can look at, or any inclusive websites? I think in a lot of ways I'm struggling with the usage of clauses, pronouns, and even omissions like this, but I haven't found an effective way of learning them and using them correctly.

Comment: @LuluCailoo A solid understanding of grammar is a useful shortcut to dealing with the language and sorting out the structure of sentences--up to a point. But eventually you get past that point, and grammar becomes a matter of very fine distinctions that get *between* you and the language. I suspect you yourself are past that point and you would do better just to read and speak as much as possible. After all, it's **use** of the language that is the real teacher, and once you're reasonably fluent you *absorb* the grammar without any real need to specify it.